# Is there any way to get warnings (not errors) for noImplicitAny noncompliance?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a lot of code that I'm porting to Typescript with missing types.  For now, I'd like my IDE (WebStorm) to just highlight places that need typing, and I'll slowly get them fixed up.

If `tsconfig.json` had a `warning` setting for `noImplicitAny`, that would be ideal.  Another alternative would be a tslint rule, but I don't know if the tslint engine is up to this job.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: The compiler will create (override) the js files even if it raises errors (unless the `--noEmitOnError` flag is used), so technically those are warnings...

Comment: @NitzanTomer Yes, I know.  I don't want to have to wade through dozens of these messages to find others of more import, on every compile.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to do this with TypeScript-ESLint, now that TSLint has been deprecated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193839)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

*As antoine129 pointed out in the comments,there is actually no `noImplicitAny` eslint rule. I was thinking of `no-explicit-any`. One approach would be to have`noImplictAny` on in the tsconfig and set `no-explicit-any: "warn"` in the `.eslintrc`, but you would have to add all the `any`s first.*

**OLD ANSWER (incorrect)**:

[The Typescript ESLint plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin) can do this.
Since this question was posted, TSLint has been deprecated in favour of using ESLint with `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.

To get eslint warnings instead of compiler errors, you could turn the `noImplicitAny` flag off in `tsconfig.json`, and set `noImplicitAny` to `"warn"` in the rules section of your `.eslintrc`.

Comment: `noImplicitAny` is not an Eslint rule

Comment: @antoine129 You're right. I can't delete this answer because it was accepted, but I updated it.

Answer (score 3):

you can either enable noImplicitAny as true, or strict as true (would enable noImplicitAny and several other rules), in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is the IDE rather than the TypeScript language or compiler that you need to work on.

If your IDE allows you to set the level of warnings, you can tell it to make these informational. Otherwise, you'll need to flip/flop by switching on `noImplicitAny` while you are working on fixing your older code and the switching it back off again when you feel you have got far enough.

Comment: Well... no.  While IDE internal inspections are usually individually tweakable for severity, I've never seen an IDE where it allows one to tweak the severity of specific *compiler* errors.  And it's really Typescript that's more wrong in this case; these would usually be considered compiler warnings, not errors.

Comment: Is the TypeScript compiler wrong? You have switched on the flag that says "don't allow implicit `any` types" and you are also annoyed that it does so? There is no option that does exactly what you want in the exact way you want it. Just use the option temporarily to discover and fix some instances until you can leave it on full time.