# Is there a way to make JS editor in VS Code mark identifiers with unknown/any type (which are only presumed to exist)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, typechecking, duck-typing

When pasting/moving code around in JS, it'd be useful to be able to find functions/variables which have no known type. Their type is often unknown because of code that might be missing (or type definitions that you might want to add in TS/JSDoc).

Currently, I have to hover the mouse on every identifier to check whether or not they have a known type. My current theme is Monokai, and it doesn't make this distinction.

**I wonder if there is some sort of setting/theme/extension that lets me easily see when an identifier is only presumed to exist, without guarantee** (for example, an external global variable or property). I mean something that would make these identifiers have a different color, or maybe an info/warning underline marker. I think NetBeans might have a feature somewhat like this, because I remember global vars having a different color.

Comment: *All* functions and variables in JavaScript have unknown type. If you want what you're asking for, use TypeScript or FlowType or something like that.

Comment: While it's generally a good idea to declare a variable, function name, object or member for future programmers, it's not a requirement of JavaScript to do so.  Some editors have the ability to "lint while you type", but the language and the interpreters don't care.

Comment: Yeah, I know declaring types in JS it's not required. But I use JSDoc/.d.ts to declare types, to make sure things have the types I expect, because I don't like duck typing. VSCode does a good job infering things, my question is just about whether or not there is a way to see this clearly in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when an identifier is only presumed to exist, without guarantee - for example, an external global variable or property

That sounds more like you are looking to find *undeclared* variables. That's pretty simple due to the good scoping rules in modern JavaScript, and most linters will complain about (and highlight) these by default. For example, take [the `no-undef` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) in eslint.

> Find functions/variables which have no known type. Their type is often unknown because of code that might be missing (or type definitions that you might want to add in TS/JSDoc).

This sounds more like a typescript question. But yes, there are tools that will complain about variables whose type was not declared / could not be inferred as well. See [Is there any way to get warnings (not errors) for noImplicitAny noncompliance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42987268/1048572) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Bergi for pointing me in the right direction!

What I had to do to get these errors in JS was simply adding a `jsconfig.json` with `.compilerOptions.checkJs: true`. For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  }
}
```