# Eslint Typescript "No Implicit Any" rule

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am setting up a new typescript project with eslint. I am trying to setup eslint rules correctly so that the `tsc` command runs without errors. I have the problem with the "noImplicitAny" rule, which I use in `tsconfig.json`, but I am unable check for this in eslint.

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    ],
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        project: ["tsconfig.json"],
        sourceType: "module",
    },
    rules: {
        "no-undef": "warn",
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
            node: {
                extensions: [".js", ".ts"],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

In short I want the eslint to check for the implicit any and warn about its usage. How can I configure the rules in `.eslintrc.js` to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987268/is-there-any-way-to-get-warnings-not-errors-for-noimplicitany-noncompliance

Comment: I've checked that thread, it suggest setting `noImplicitAny` in .eslintrc, however no such rule exist in ESLint. I know there is `'@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any'` but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a number of `no-unsafe-*` rules that have been implemented in TypeScript-ESLint:

- [`no-unsafe-call`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-call.md) - forbids calling an expression typed as `any`
- [`no-unsafe-member-access`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-member-access.md) - forbids using `any` as a member name
- [`no-unsafe-argument`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-argument.md) - forbids passing `any` as a function parameter
- [`no-unsafe-assignment`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-assignment.md) - forbids using `any` in an assignment

These are all standalone rules, but they've also all been integrated into
Typescript-ESLint's official
[recommended-requiring-type-checking](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended-requiring-type-checking.ts) config.

```
extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
```

On a similar note, there's [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md). Put all of these together, and you should be fully protected against `any` problems.

Comment: `any` problems. Lol.

Comment: Yes, I have `any` problems with setting `this` up... If I have this code `(value || '').toLowerCase()` where `value` is implicitly any, I expect the IDE/eslint/TypeScript to give/show me an error, but it doesn't... Is the `no-unsafe-call` rule only for explicitly typed `any` variables?? What about covering for implictly typed `any`? My IDE/editor knows the difference, as when I hover over `.toLowerCase()` it says `any` rather than providing the documentation for the String prototype function.... I just want it to complain to me so that I avoid deploying RT errors... Is that possible?

Comment: So I just figured this out! Power of self-Q/A lol... Needed to add to my parserOptions, as shown [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting/). I figured this out by making a minimal demo by utilizing the [typescript-eslint online playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/) to test out the `no-unsafe-call` rule working in real-time! That playground was super helpful for me, and I hope maybe this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

the previous usage using typedef was annoying because even if typescript could implicitly know what it was, it still marked it with a warning.

I am now using the following rule:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'warn',
```

This warns when a variable is truly any from what I have seen.

PREVIOUSLY:

eslint refuses to add a no-implicit-any due to the fact it duplicates a typescript rule.

They did however make a transition rule that should not be used permanently which does what you wanted.  You should remove this rule once you can turn these options on in your tsconfig file.

This allows warning for implicit parameters or arguments in normal and arrow functions.  There are more options than the ones commented out, documentation linked below.

One issue I have with this rule is that if typescript can implicitly figure out what it should be, this rule still marks it as an issue.  Since it should only be temporary till you can turn on the typescript rule, I just ignore those issues.

```
    '@typescript-eslint/typedef': [
      'warn',
      {
        parameter: true,
        arrowParameter: true,
        // variableDeclaration: true,
        // memberVariableDeclaration: true,
        // objectDestructuring: true,
      },
    ],
```

link to github issue not allowing no-implicit-any
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3979

doucmentation for typedef information
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/typedef.md