# Why is it possible to pass a value of type 'any' to a typed parameter without an error?

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript transpiler does not emit an error for the following code:

```
function test1(test: any) {
    test2(test);
}

function test2(test: string) {

}
```

I expected an error to be emitted for this code because if an object of type 'any' can be passed to a parameter of type 'string' without any error, then the code could cause a non-string could be passed to test2 at runtime. It should be trivial for the transpiler to know there is a potential type safety violation here?

I thought the point of TypeScript was to ensure type safety at compile time? What am I missing here? Is there an option I need to enable in tsconfig.json or something?

**Edit:**

I don't think my generic example that I included above is getting my point across. Here is a snippet from my actual application. The code is part of a Google Apps Script application, and I am using the `@google/clasp` typings.

```
// 'sheet' is of type GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet
// The return value of this function is any[][]
// There is nothing I can do to change this, it is an import from a library
const cells = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, -1, -1);

for (const cell of cells) {
    const registration = cell[0]; // any
    const profileName = cell[1]; // any
    const uuid = cell[2]; // any

    //
    // The signature of this constructor is as follows:
    // constructor(aircraft: InputAircraft, profileName: string, uuid: string)
    //
    // Passing 'any' to the parameters of this constructor does not cause any 
    // warning or error, even with strict=true in my tsconfig.conf or even 
    // with eslint set up with the @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any rule 
    // turned on.
    //

    yield new InputProfile(registration, profileName, uuid);
}
```

Comment: Yeah - using `any` defeats the purpose of TypeScript since it's not type-safe, which is why many linters and some config settings warn against it. Easy solution: just never use `any`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance What settings cause TypeScript to emit a warning for the use of any? This is precisely what I want. The issue that prompted my posting is that a library I am using returns any[][] from a particular function, and I passed one of the 'any' objects to a typed function without realizing a type safety violation had occurred. Obviously this means that I effectively wrote a bug into the code, but I would expect TypeScript to warn me of this bug, since that is literally the entire point of static type checking.

Comment: I'd suggest [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) and [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193839

Comment: @CertainPerformance `noImplicitAny` does not work (no error or warning is produced). I also have `strict` on.

Comment: Yeah, since you're using *explicit* any - but `noImplicitAny` helps with *other* `any` problems. Combine with strict and a linter and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The issue is that the library I am using explicitly returns `any[][]` and I can't change that. For this reason I don't want to use a linter that will error on any use of `any`. The issue isn't the use of `any`, per say, it is that an object of type `any` is being assigned to a typed parameter or variable. I would expect TypeScript to emit an error or warning in this situation UNLESS a runtime type check is performed.

Comment: As per the documentation on [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), `...When a value is of type any,... call it like a function, assign it to (or from) a value of any type, or pretty much anything else that’s syntactically legal.`. So what you are asking for won't be possible outright by the compiler itself.

Answer (score 1):

`any` is intentionally left in as a way *around* the type checker, for working with legacy untyped Javascript code. It should *only* be used in situations where you have code which is not typed or which cannot be easily typed.

With `--strict` (which includes `noImplicitAny`, among other things), you'll get a warning if a variable is ever *accidentally* of type `any`. If you write `any`, the compiler assumes you meant it and know what you're doing. If you really want to go without the ability to use `any` *at all*, then [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) is an ESLint setting you can turn on.

Comment: A library I am using in my application returns any[][] from a function. I want to receive an error or a warning from TypeScript if I pass the 'any' elements of this array to any type parameter (or assign them to a typed variable). However, I am not receiving any error or warning despite the fact that I have `strict` on.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want. If you want to avoid `any`, use `no-explicit-any`. If you *have* an `any` and don't want it to be `any`, then cast it. If you have an `any` but don't want to cast it or do anything with it, then... well, just discard it, because at that point it's of no use to you. What do you plan to *do* with an `any[][]` if not cast or use the elements?

Comment: I want TypeScript to give me an error if I inadvertently pass the `any` object to a typed parameter or variable without first performing a runtime type check on it (i.e. `typeof value == 'string'`).

Comment: Then cast it to `unknown[][]`. `unknown` is the type that means "I can't do anything to this without casting". `any` means "I am allowed to do anything, trust me".

Comment: In order to KNOW to cast it to `unknown[][]`, the programmer needs to first be aware that it is `any[][]`. What if I forget that a particularly library function returns `any`? I want an error from the compiler or linter for this situation, but I can't figure out any way to accomplish this. Please see my updated original post.

Comment: The is no way to make passing `any` to something a type error. The library should probably be returning type `unknown[][]` instead. So you could patch the library and use the patched version. You could wrap the library with your own function that casts the results. Or you could use a library with better typings.

Comment: I agree with @JoeCrivello. For example, Express' `Request.body` is `any` and it would be useful to get a compilation error indicating its being passed as a parameter to a function that expects a typed parameter.